# Unity3D - Make texture edges not stretch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been searching around for this one for a bit, and unfortunately I can't seem to find any good, consistent results.  So, in the Unity UI system, buttons can stretch without becoming pixelated or distorted.  This is because the texture is split up into 9 parts - the corners, middle, and sides.

[image]

This works because the button's middle and sides are stretched, but not the corners.  Then, the button appears not pixelated, at any dimension.

---

So, the question is as follows: How can I do the same thing for a transparent, unlit texture in 3D space?  I have a speech bubble texture on a flat plane that I know how to re-scale to fit the text in the speech bubble.

I've set the texture type to Multiple Sprite, and divided it up into 9 parts.  However, I cannot seem to find where I can set the texture to act like the UI button does, and I'm not sure that this is even possible in this way in 3D space.

[image: Viewing the speech bubble object]
[image: Viewing the speech bubble sprite]

Is there a way, or should I just make the different parts of the texture different objects, and move them together?  That would seem very inefficient and ugly compared to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you are asking, you would need to create tiles for this speech bubble and then write a script that procedurally builds a speech bubble based on the plane's scale value. You could also try just changing the texture's Filter Mode to Point.

However I really don't think you should be using textures for this anyway. Why not just use a Unity Canvas and set the Render Mode to World Space? Then you can just set your text box to be a sprite, not a texture, and set its filter mode to Point (See below). This would also make it a lot easier for when you want there to be text in the speech bubble later on.

[image: Point Filter Mode]

Comment: The world canvas thing is an idea I thought of but didn't give too much thought.  Looking at it now, it would probably be the best way to go.  Thanks :)